# Magento 1.9.x sessions and auto-discovery on AWS ElastiCache

Tags: php, magento, amazon-web-services, memcached, amazon-elasticache

I'm trying to implement AWS ElastiCache auto-discovery for memcache on our Magento web application but I'm encountering some issues. I have followed the information in the documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PHPAutoDiscoverySetup.html) but I'm still getting following error:

```
2016-11-02T14:47:18+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (memcached). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (uat1-memcache.sbutwp.cfg.euw1.cache.amazonaws.com:11211)  in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm assuming this might have something to do with overwriting the Memcached client class with:

```
$dynamic_client = new Memcached('persistent-id');
$dynamic_client->setOption(Memcached::OPT_CLIENT_MODE, Memcached::DYNAMIC_CLIENT_MODE);
$dynamic_client->addServer($server_endpoint, $server_port);
```

but I'm not entirely sure how to initialize the memcached class with those options using session_start which is what Magento uses to initialize the session.

Any help will be much appreciated.